# In Grafana how do you get multi lines from multi-select variable and a single query

Tags: grafana, promql

I have a simple query and 2 variables, one of them is multi-select. What I'd like to do is get 1 line per multi-select.

```
{__name__ ="fusion:$METRIC:$POD"}
```

`METRIC` is a multi select and `POD` is a single select. So, I'd like to show, say, 4 metrics for the same pod.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you have multi-select value in Grafana, use regex selector `=~`.

For PromQL queries Grafana will automatically substitute your variable with value like `(val1|val2|val3)`.

So your query in this case would be

```
{__name__ =~"fusion:$METRIC:$POD"}
```